# On server my application is looking for uppercase table name instead of lowercase

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have this table on my local xampp , the table name is `tags` , this works perfectly fine on my local system, but when I upload this table to my server I get the following error:

[image]

The tables I have under the table `peckinga_blog` are the following:

[image]

As you can see `tags` is one of them , Also for the `tags` table I have the following migrations in my laravel application:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTagsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->mediumText('tag');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('Tags');
    }
}
```

Now why am I getting this this error in spite of my database clearly being available ? What can I do so that my server will look for the database `tags` instead of `Tags` ?

Comment: change all instances of "Tags" in your code to "tags"

Comment: Change it from Tags to tags? or change your tablename in the DB from tags to Tags?

Comment: If i rename `tags` to `Tags` in phpmyadmin , i get an error that reads `tags` already exists .

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html explains

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the following line in my code:

```
    $tags = DB::table('Tags')->get();
```

worked perfectly locally on my windows `XAMPP`, but needed to change it to:

```
    $tags = DB::table('tags')->get();
```

to work on my server.

Comment: Windows filesystem is case insensitive, Linux fileystsems are not. I'm guessing you do some WindowsDev and so are used to pascal case?

Comment: @RichardVanbergen yes :) :)

Comment: i would say next time be a little careful with your bounty applying as i was going to give this answer but you self answered before the bounty was up.

Answer (score 9):

Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix or Linux. Table names in MySQL are file system entries, so they are case insensitive if the underlying file system is.

Although after applying the migration, it should work But in case if it is not working and you want both statements i.e. lower case and upper case name in table to succeed, you need to put the following line

> lower_case_table_names = 1

in your /etc/my.cnf or wherever you keep your MySQL configuration.

Doctrine generated capital/CamelCase table names and MySQL stored them as lowercase!

Or

1. Before export the database from local you can do these steps:
2. open your MySQL configuration file: [drive]\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
3. look up for: # The MySQL server [mysqld]
4. add this right below it: lower_case_table_names = 2
5. save the file and restart MySQL service

Be sure to add the system variable to [mysqld] section of the configuration file.

For more information you can check the [MySQL Reference Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

Answer (score 6):

the case sensitivity depends on your underlying filesystem, which explains the discrepancy between your local and production machine.

since this is a common problem, I'd recommend to use lowercase allover as a convention. change your `Tags` to `tags` in your migrations and also in your [model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) and you should be good to go.

if you need to rename your table, rename it first to `something_else`, and than again to `tags`.